# Is my grammar correct for this context-free language?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

$\{a^nb^2a^n \mid n \ge0\}$

I'm studying for my final and I came across this language. I haven't dealt with characters of the same length on opposite ends with something in between.

I came up with the following grammar, but I think it accepts strings that it should not such as:
$abb, bba$, etc.

$$\begin{align}
S&\rightarrow X\\
X&\rightarrow XbbX \mid \epsilon\\
A&\rightarrow aA \mid \epsilon
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your grammar doesn't generate any word with an $a$ in it.

Answer (score 3):

In dealing with CFGs, it's often useful to work from the inside out. Clearly
$$
S\rightarrow aSa
$$
will generate all strings of the form $a^nSa^n$, for $n\ge 0$. Then all you have to do is allow the possibility that $S$ will also eventually generate $bb$, which we can do by the production $S\rightarrow bb$, giving the grammar
$$
S\rightarrow aSa\mid bb
$$
or, if you wanted to be explicit about the $bb$ central part, you could write
$$\begin{align}
S&\rightarrow aSa \mid T\\
T&\rightarrow bb
\end{align}$$
The problem with your grammar is that it can't guarantee that there will be the same number of $a$s on each end of a generated string.